# Does Bitul Bshishim apply to Chametz?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, passover, chametz-leaven

You’ve heard of the Halacha that a meat item smaller than a sixtieth in a dairy product is considered nullified, right? Well does that apply to something chametz in an otherwise non-chametz product?

Comment: As far as I recall, chameitz is not nullified even b'mashehu.

Comment: The Rambam in Mishneh Torah states that even a little mixing of chametz into another product, makes the whole product prohibited.

Comment: Shmuel, even bidieved?

Comment: @RaphaelChilungu yes even bdieved

Answer (score 5):

This is the lashon of Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim Siman 447:1

חמץ בפסח אוסר תערובתו בין במינו בין שלא במינו במשהו אפילו בהנאה: הגה וצריך לשרוף הכל ולא סגי בפדיון דמי החמץ ולמכור השאר (מרדכי פ"ק דפסחים ופסקי מהרא"י סק"ד ותשובת מהר"י ברי"ן) מיהו כלים שנתבשל בהם מותרים לאחר הפסח ואין צריכין שבירה או הגעלה: (ד"ע ותוספות פרק כל שעה)  **ודין תערובתו כדין שאר תערובות אלא שמה שאוסר בשאר תערובות פחות מששים אוסר בחמץ במשהו** אבל אם בשאר תערובת לא היה צריך ששים אלא קליפה או נטילת מקום אף בחמץ כן שחם בחם בלא רוטב די בקליפה כשאר איסורים וכן אם נגע ככר חמץ בככר מצה ושניהם חמין ואין שם דבר המפעפען לא אסר אלא מקום מגעו בלבד לפי שאינו מבליע יותר: הגה ובדין ריחא מילתא לענין תבשיל שיש בו חמץ עם שאר תבשילין יש מקילין במקום דהיה מותר בשאר אסורים (מרדכי פרק כל שעה) ויש מחמירין דמשהו מיהא איכא (הגהות סמ"ק ותוס' דע"א) ודוקא במקום ששייך בו ריחא אלא דבשאר אסורים לאו מלתא היא כמו שיתבאר ביו"ד סי' ק"ח בסיעתא דשמיא:

Chametz on Pesach makes a mixture forbidden, whether or not the mixture is of the same type as the chametz, in any amount and one cannot even derive benefit from it.  And one must burn it all and its not sufficient to redeem the value of the chametz and sell the rest (מרדכי פ"ק דפסחים ופסקי מהרא"י סק"ד ותשובת מהר"י ברי"ן). However, vessels which one cooked this mixture in are permitted to be used after Pesach and don't need to be destroyed or scalded (ד"ע ותוספות פרק כל שעה). **The laws of mixture of chametz are the same as the laws of other forbidden mixture, except whereas other mixtures are permitted where less than 1/60 is present, chametz mixtures remain forbidden where any amount is present.** But if in the rest of the mixture there was no need for sixty, rather just a peel or taking a place, so to with chametz, it is hot in the heat without a sufficient sauce in the peel like other forbidden mixtures, and if a loaf of chametz touches a loaf of matzah and they are both hot and there is nothing bubbling, only the place of contact is forbidden, since it didn't absorb further. And the law of Reichah Milsah  regarding cooked dishes which have chametz in them and other cooked dishes: there is room to be lenient in a place where it would be permitted with regard to other forbidden mixtures (מרדכי פרק כל שעה). And there are those are strict (הגהות סמ"ק ותוס' דע"א). This is all specifically where Reichah is relevant. Rather, regarding other forbidden mixtures, it is not relevant, as we'll see in Yoreah Deah 98 with Hashem's help.

There are 2 reasons why chamatez is not batel bashishim:

Mishneh Berurah (there) says: חמץ בפסח וכו' - מדאורייתא הוי חמץ כשאר איסורים שנתערבו שאינן אוסרין תערובתן אלא כדי ליתן טעם בתערובות דהיינו עד ששים אלא שחכמים החמירו בו כיון דאית ביה כרת ולא בדילי מניה כולי שתא וי"א משום דהוי דבר שיש לו מתירין לאחר הפסח וכדלקמן בסי"א:

1. It has the serious punishment of Karet
2. Its a דבר שיש לו מתירין

Hope this helps :)

Comment: It should be noted that this is a law about Chametz on Pesach itself. Chametz falling into a mixture of non-chametz should be nullified in 60 if the event happened before Passover arrived.